Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
When changing the hostname in the icewm-session, the application startup breaks down. Such errors are written in the logs .xsession-errors when launching applications:
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: :0

When i start the distribution (native build), xdm starts. After logging in to xdm, the script .xsession is run from the user's home directory, which contains:
#!/bin/bash

icewm-session -s

Next, the icewm session starts.
If I log in again, then everything works fine. But as soon as I change the hostname, it becomes impossible to launch applications, although there are no problems in the icewm session.
I created a issue for the problem, but it was rejected. Do I need to configure something additionally?

Any Desktop environment sits on top of the XOrg Server, and the XOrg Server  looks at the hostname in /etc/hosts or elsewhere, i.e hostnamectl to set your hostname before launching, to ensure it's launching the local copy, and not a request from a remote/ssh/vpn. Changing it while the XOrg Server is active breaks as you've found (The current running XOrg hostname is compared with the new hostname and since the hostnames aren't equal, reauthorization is required to "approve" the new location of $SISPLAY).  Perhaps the real question should be why are you changing your hostname
